# How to pass TimeSpan data using query property attributes from one XAML Page to the other XAML Page?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, timespan

Maybe to some of you it might be elemental issue, but I am really at loss to resolve **System.InvalidCastException:** 'Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.TimeSpan'.

I have two XAML pages, and I need to pass TimeSpan parameter from one page to the other (so that I can use TimePicker on the other page).

The first xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp2.Views.DateTimePage"
              xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TestApp2.ViewModels" 
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp2.ViewModels"  
                    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:TestApp2.Models" 
             x:DataType="viewmodels:DateTimePageViewModel"
             Title="DateTimePage"
             >
        <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Tap">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                        NumberOfTapsRequired="2"
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DateTimePageViewModel}}, Path=TimePickerTapped}"        
                        CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            
        </Label>

            <TimePicker x:Name="timeFromTimePicker" Time="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay}" />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and

```
namespace TestApp2.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class DateTimePage : ContentPage
    {
        public DateTimePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new DateTimePageViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel behind the first page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using TestApp2.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp2.ViewModels
{
    public class DateTimePageViewModel: BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Command TimePickerTapped { get; }
        

        private TimeSpan time;
        public TimeSpan Time
        {
            get => time;
            
            set
            {
                time = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public DateTimePageViewModel()
        {
            TimePickerTapped = new Command(OnTimePickerSelected);
            time = new TimeSpan(17, 0, 0);
        }

        async void OnTimePickerSelected()
        {
            if (time != null)
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TransferDateTimePage)}?" +
                    $"{nameof(TransferDateTimePageViewModel.Time)}={Time}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second XAML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestApp2.Views.TransferDateTimePage"
                    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:TestApp2.ViewModels" 
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp2.ViewModels"  
                    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:TestApp2.Models" 
             x:DataType="viewmodels:TransferDateTimePageViewModel"
             >
        <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <TimePicker x:Name="timeFromTimePicker" Time="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and

```
namespace TestApp2.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TransferDateTimePage : ContentPage
    {
        public TransferDateTimePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = new TransferDateTimePageViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

and View Model behind second page is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp2.ViewModels
{

        [QueryProperty(nameof(Time), nameof(Time))]
        public class TransferDateTimePageViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged      //, IQueryAttributable
        {
            private TimeSpan time;
            public TimeSpan Time
            {
                get => time;
                set
                {
                    time = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }

            public TransferDateTimePageViewModel()
            {

            }
       }
   }
```

I think that error somehow relates to

```
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TransferDateTimePage)}?" +
                $"{nameof(TransferDateTimePageViewModel.Time)}={Time}"); 

ViewModel behind first page code
```

and    passing parameter to second page:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(Time), nameof(Time))]
```

I really do not know how to resolve this. I tried to search Internet extensively for several days, but I was unable to resolve this so far.

I need the user to be able to edit on second page the time appearing on first .

Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of Jason advice herein above I finally found the solution, which is to change the View Model of second page this way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TestApp2.ViewModels
{
    public class TransferDateTimePageViewModel : BaseViewModel, INotifyPropertyChanged, IQueryAttributable        
    {

        public void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, string> query)
        {
            string Time = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(query["MyTime"]);
            LoadMyTime(Time);
        }


        void LoadMyTime(string Time)
        {
            _ = TimeSpan.TryParse(Time, out myTime);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyTime));
        }

        private TimeSpan myTime;

        public TimeSpan MyTime
           {
            get => myTime;
            set
               {
                   myTime = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged();
               }
           }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation#pass-data)

> **Primitive** data can be passed as string-based query parameters

**primitive** usually means simple value types, not complex objects like `TimeSpan`

to pass objects, use this syntax

```
var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Time", myTimespanObject }
};
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"mypage", false, navigationParameter);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but now I am getting syntax error: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.TimeSpan>' to 'bool'

when trying  suggested code:   

var navigationParameter = new Dictionary<string, TimeSpan>
            {
                  { "Time", Time }
            };
           
            await  Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(TransferDateTimePage)}",
                        navigationParameter);

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Thank you. Except now it's giving me 

No overload for method 'GoToAsync' takes 3 arguments.

Am I still missing something?

Comment: My apologies, I assumed you were using MAUI.  It doesn’t look like XF shell supports this

Comment: Thank you. OK, if this doesn't work in XF, I have no choice but finally to move to MAUI then. Which is long overdue anyway.